# How to move folders from one location to another using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So i have a directory full of folders that i want to move to another area, also i only want to move the folders that were created 30 days ago or more. I have a script that does what i need for files but it doesnt seem to work for folders. Script is below

Script for moving files

```
 param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$destinationRoot
 )

$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |
Foreach-Object {
    $content = $path + "\" + $_.Name

    $year = (Get-Item $content).LastWriteTime.year.ToString()
    $monthNumber = (Get-Item $content).LastWriteTime.month
    $month = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($monthNumber)

    $destination = $destinationRoot + "\" + $year + "\" + $month 

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination

    Move-Item -Path $content -Destination $destination -force

}
```

The Get-ChildItem portion does not seem to pull directories in like it should.

Comment: Please update your question to describe what, specifically, doesn't work.

Comment: what if a file thats less then 30 days is in a folder that is greater then 30 days?

Comment: @ArcSet I only care about the folder created date, not the file created date.

Comment: @mkdement0 the get childitem does not seem to retrieve folders correctly

Comment: just use `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse`. Honestly there are quite a few things that would make this script better. Let me see if i cant do a fast rewrite

Comment: @ArcSet my experience with PowerShell is very limited, so thank you

Comment: There is a trailing pipe symbol missing at this line `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }`

Comment: PS do you want created or last write time?

Comment: What a creative spelling of my username - I do hope the embedded insult (`dement`) was accidental. Generally, please always _directly update your question_ with clarifications, don't post them as _comments_. ArcSet's recommendation to use of `-Directory` (PSv3+) is a helpful simplification, but unless your problem is truly just the missing `|` that LotPings points out, your code _should_ correctly target directories.

Comment: @ArcSet Created

Comment: @mklement0 apologies for the name misspell. Was not intentional

Comment: @mklement0 I think there is a flaw with gci recursing and in the foreach combining `$path` with the current name without taking into account that the current item might be a (sub-)subdir of $path - so $content points to a non existing folder.

Comment: Good point, @LotPings - ergo the problem isn't with `Get-ChildItem`, but with the (unnecessary) path construction inside the `ForEach-Object` block: `$content = $_.FullName` might do (the potential for further improvements notwithstanding, and possibly the need to switch from `.LastWriteTime` to `.CreationTime`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the script i decided to change some things up

```
Function Move-FilesByAge(){
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Destination,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][timespan]$AgeLimit
     )

    Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory -Recurse | ?{
        $($_.CreationTimeUtc.Add($AgeLimit)) -lt $((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())
    } | %{
        $Dpath = $Destination + "\" + $_.CreationTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy") + "\" + $_.CreationTimeUtc.ToString("MMMM")
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Dpath
        Move-Item $_ -Destination $Dpath -Force
    }
}

Move-FilesByAge -Source C:\Test -Destination C:\Test2 -AgeLimit (New-TimeSpan -days 30)
```

This can lead to a major issue. If a folder with the same name exists then it will pop a error that folder exists.

Since you are new to powershell lets go over some basics about this script. In Powershell we love Piping `|` which you did well in the original. We also a big fan of aliases Where-Object `?{}`, Foreach-Object `%{}`.

Get-ChildItem has a built in switch for just returning directories `-directory`.

You are also using last **LastWriteTime** when you should be using **CreationTime**. **CreationTimeUtc** allows you to standardize your time across timezones by providing a base timezone.

Date.ToString(Date Format Here). IS a great way to shorten how you parse the date as a string. `.ToString("yyyy")` gets you the year in 4 numbers like 2018. `.ToString("MMMM")` will get the month by name like March.

Comment: You could simplify things with the `-format` operator: `$Dpath = "{0}\{1:yyyy\\MMMM}" -f $Destination,$_.CreationTimeUtc` to include a literal character in a format string `\` which has a meaning it needs to be escaped `\\`.

Comment: Hmm backticks and backslashes don't play together nicely in a comment: To include a literal character in a format string \ which has a meaning it needs to be escaped \\